# How to check if Var equals a different var - IMacro + Javascript

Tags: javascript, imacros

I have got 2 vars, which are vis and newvis.

I want to check if var vis equals the same as var newvis

I am using the javascript side of IMacros.

```
for(var i=0;i<1;i++)
{ 
if (vis !== 'newvis'){
iimDisplay("Same Vis")
}
else {
iimDisplay("Different Vis")
}}
```

When running this it says var vis and var newvis are same when there not?

Comment: Close but your second var in your if statement is a string not a var. Remove the quotes. And replace the ! With = As well because that will cause your if to run if it's falsey-true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code states:

if vis is not exactly equal to the string "newvis" display "Same vis"

I think you're meaning:

```
for(var i=0;i<1;i++){
   if(vis === newvis){
      iimDisplay("Same Vis");
   }else{
      iimDisplay("Different Vis")
   }
}
```

Comment: Won't let me tick it yet however this has worked.Thank you